# installing d3 using npm causes contextify errors

Tags: d3.js, npm

Getting some mystifying contextify errors (but other installs seem to go fine.)

```
npm install d3

    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  
[C:\Users\dinesh\m3\node_modules\d3\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\dinesh\m3\node_modules\d3\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
```

Comment: Maybe try `npm install --msvs_version=2012`? Taken from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/306), which pointed to [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/168#issuecomment-21294873).

Comment: @meetamit thanks, interesting. I just tried that and it failed same place. I tried with --verbose option, and it show the trailing logs are `about to build .\node_modules\d3\node_modules\jsdom` followed by `about to build .\node_modules\d3`. I am unsure what that means... (for the moment I have installed the d3 package manually)

Answer (score 19):

You've probably moved on at this point, but for future googlers:

Upgrade to D3.js v3.5.4+

`jsdom` is a dependency of `d3`, and `jsdom` requires `contextify`, which uses native modules (`node-gyp`).  Native modules are hard to build on some platforms, so `d3` made `jsdom` a development dependency (not installed by default) as of v3.5.4.

Related: [D3.js commit](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/9c3df31216aa28d8252b216b558cbb5907480b5b) and [D3.js issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1986).

Comment: I wish I could give you 10 upvotes. Installing `node-gyp` is a pain.